# Protractor not working with Firefox 40.0.2

Tags: angularjs, node.js, automation, protractor

Protractor not working with Firefox 40.0.2.

Earlier it was working fine with Firefox 33.0. Recently I have updated into FF 40.0 and I am facing this issue.Any work around for this issue?

Following is the error:

{UnknownError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Comment: What protractor version are you using?

Comment: @alecxe We are using Protractor 2.1.0.

Do i need to update protractor to support FF 40.0.2?
In that case 
which version I need to update?
How to update protractor?

Comment: We can run Firefox 40.0.2 with selenium web-driver 2.47.1.I have updated my selenium standalone server into 2.47.1 and I am able to execute it successfully in Firefox 40.0.2.Hence closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think selenium 2.47 (which is the latest version of now) supports firefox 40.0 yet. Here's the link of the changelog of selenium which shows the supported version of firefox - [Selenium ChangeLog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG). Until selenium supports latest version of firefox, protractor doesn't support it either as its a wrapper over selenium webdriver. Hope it helps.

Comment: So what is the Firefox version I can use with selenium web-driver 2.47.1?

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan, As of selenium webdriver v2.47.0, firefox v39 is supported. Please refer change log for more info.

Comment: We can run Firefox 40.0.2 with selenium web-driver 2.47.1.I have updated my selenium standalone server into 2.47.1 and I am able to execute it successfully in Firefox 40.0.2.Hence closing the question.